# How to test F# on linux

Tags: linux, f#, visual-studio-code

How do you actually test F# on Linux?
After many hours of trying everything short of bruteforcing every atom/VScode terminal that I could open - I haven't made any progress.
Even the official guide just hand-waves, briefly introduces a few frameworks and that's that.

### Simple question description

I have a hello world app with one function opened inside VScode with mono and ionide. Thus:

```fs
module Please =
    let itSpeaks number = "hello"
```

I have downloaded FsCheck, FsCheck.xunit, xunit, unqoute, xunit.runners using paket and added references to ".fsproj". I have created a test. Lets say:

```fs
open Xunit.Extensions
open Swensen.Unquote

module Test =

    [<Theory>]
    [<InlineData(-1)>]
    let ``it actually speaks`` (number: int) =
        let actual : string = Please.itSpeaks number
        let expected = "hello"
        test <@ expected = actual @>
```

What now?

Additional: I'd settle for an atom solution, or nUnit, or at least a sign that I'm moving in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Build it and pass to `xunit.console.exe`.

Comment: If I had found the link, I would paste there. There was a .net core F# tutorial leveraging xunit. Try to search it by yourself.

Comment: You might want to use Expecto instead of xUnit.net, since Ionide has built-in support for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at using [ionide](http://ionide.io/),  [paket](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) and [fake](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/). Your packet dependencies can include the following:

```
// avoid new netcore dependencies for now
nuget NUnit = 3.5.0

nuget NUnit.Runners
```

Hopefully you know how to add a reference to your project. I use fsproj files and have below my existing **ItemGroup** for **Reference Include**:

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="nunit.framework">
        <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
</Choose>
```

with fake you have a build.fsx file. For me I use the Nunit 3 built-in:

```
buildDebugReferences
|> Testing.NUnit3.NUnit3 (fun p -> { p with WorkingDir = buildDebugResultDir })
```

where "buildDebugReferences" is in my **FileIncludes** path to my library built as:

```
let buildDebugReferences = !! buildDebugFilter
```

In my code I put conditionals for the framework:

```
#if DEBUG
open NUnit.Framework
#endif
...
#if DEBUG
[<TestFixture>]
type InternalTestsNunit () =
    [<Test>]
    static member ``Get Answer`` = Assert.AreEqual(1, 1)
#endif
```

This is all in the primary library being built. So I get to have my tests right below my code in the same file. I do this for simple one line tests. More tests that are complicated get put in a separate project just for Nunit. Thank you. Good day.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that you are running VS Code and linux, I assume that you are using .net core.  @Fyodor Soikin helped me a couple of days ago with a similar question on this thread.

[How to unit test F# on dotnet Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968229/is-there-a-way-to-unit-test-f-projects-in-net-core)

I have not seen this documented anywhere but it worked for me.
Setup a test project in C# by typing

```
dotnet new -t xunittest
```

It will create a project.json for a C# project.  That's close to what you want, but it's missing the F# bits.  I diffed that file against a project.json file from an F# project and copied the relevant F# lines into the C# project.json file. The updated project.json looks like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "compilerName": "fsc",
    "compile": {
      "includeFiles": [
        "Tests.fs"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.3.0",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-*",
    "---Name of project to test goes here--": {
       "target": "project"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-compile-fsc": "1.0.0-preview2.1-*"
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {            
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore": "1.0.0-alpha-160629"
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if your test project is referencing another project, you will have to replace "---Name of project to tests goes here--" with the name of the project you are testing.

After updating the test project's project.json file, run:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet test
```

You could certainly just start with the project.json above, but I mentioned creating the C# version to see how it came about.

Comment: While this got me furthest, the combination of depending on dotnet core and the ceremony involved in resolving dependencies manually doesn't work for me. I'll try the other frameworks before accepting this.