# Debugging xunit tests written in F# in .NET Core and Visual Studio Code?

Tags: debugging, f#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am trying to debug xunit tests that are written with F#. I am on .NET Core and using Visual Studio Code on windows platform. Is this possible? 
P.S. I am aware there is another question regarding the matter but in this case it is F# specific.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible. A closed similar case has been posted by **Doug Ferguson**  in this link [Is there a way to unit test F# projects in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968229/is-there-a-way-to-unit-test-f-projects-in-net-core). You can try it out.